# (ASP.NET, C#) Can a backend exception affect another user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I have a situation where an error getting thrown by a process run on my server for one user and is affecting another process being run by for another user.

Basically, it looks like the other process stop working because of the error, even though the two process are totally unrelated and the pages on which my two users are not the same.

I know this is occuring because my second user has confirmed that he sees the error message even though it isn't related to him or his session.

Has anyone every experience this problem before ?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

The function that generate an alert looks like this, it is called directly in my Catch(Exception ex)

```
public static class CommonAlert
    {
        public static void GenerateAlert(Page CurrentPage, string strAlertMessage)
        {

            string script = @"ApplyJqueryUI();embedHtml({0});
                                function embedHtml(result)
                                {{
                                    alert(result)
                                }};";

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(CurrentPage,
                                        CurrentPage.GetType(),
                                        "embedHtml",
                                        string.Format(script,EncodeJsString(strAlertMessage)), true);        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your application pool will recycle after 5 errors thrown if you don't change the default settings so the session would die for the other user if there are 5 quick successive problems. Not sure why he would see the same message though, sounds highly unlikely (not saying it's false, just very very very unlikely)

Comment: I've checked and there was only 2 errors thrown one after another in a period of about an hour. Only the other user was having problem. Other users didn't seem to have any issues.

Comment: Is there anything linking the two users accounts, name etc, where the application could be deciding to post the error to a user rather than to the session?

Comment: No, the users are unrelated. There is no link between them.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand:  these users are in the same web app, right?

Comment: @RyanMcDonough are you sure you aren't referring to the application pool being disabled after five application pool crashes within a certain time period? I've not heard of application pool recycle because of simple exceptions... or maybe I've just never noticed.

Comment: ...mainly because scanner bots / crawlers can cause a bunch of useless exceptions in very quick succession, which, if this were true, would seem like there would be continual app pool recycles too.

Comment: @Ann L. : Yes both users are using the same web app/website. They are however in located in two different pages and call very different functions. The error occurs in an area that is never called by the other user.

Comment: How is the error message getting in the strAlertMessage variable? Where/how is that occurring on the backend?

Comment: The first thing I think of when someone tells me that data for one ASP.NET user is seen by a second user is caching.  Not saying it's your problem, but it's where I'd start looking.

Comment: @Joe : Do you mean caching on the server ?

Comment: @user3050439, I'm thinking about output caching.  On the server, or between the server and your users.

Answer (score 2):

How are you handling your exceptions? As Ryan McDonough mentioned above, the app pool will recycle after a specified numbers of errors occur.

Are you using static variables anywhere to capture the errors before showing them? Without seeing code this is just a guess, but if you potentially have something like the following going on, then users may see the wrong messages:

```
public static Exception _lastError;

void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _lastError = Server.GetLastError();
}
```

And then in the request, if _lastError is not null, you may be showing it. Again, just a guess...

If this is the case, consider `[ThreadStatic]` or not using static variables.

Otherwise, post an example of how you're handling your exceptions and you'll get a better answer!

Good luck!

Comment: In one particular case the error is not handle which is why I'm very puzzle as to why this particular error would affect a completely different user. We noticed the error and where it was happening using the Event Viewer. In the other, we're not using a sessions variable to track the exception. The exception is simply catch and calls a Static GenerateAlert message in the current page.